# Flowpattern doesn't exist

Tags: prolog

I have been working on a code in prolog for a while now and it is near compiling worthy and all my ideas seem to be solid so it should work when it compiles.  It is a program that consults a database file for a list of clauses and then it awaits for a query by the user which it will then pick what information it needs from the sentence and query the database appropriately but there is a block of code that keeps giving me errors complaining that the flowpattern doesn't exist in the standard predicate this may be a silly question but even with all the looking into this I have done i can't find out how to fix this problem if someone could help me out or point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the block of code that gives the error:

```
loop(STR):- 
           scan(STR,LIST),
           filter(LIST,LISroT1),
           pars(LIST1,LIST2),
           fail.

loop(STR):-    STR >< "",readquery(L),loop(L).

readquery(QUERY):-nl,nl,write("Query: "),readln(QUERY).

scan(STR,[TOK|LIST]):-
    fronttoken(STR,SYMB,STR1),!,
    upper_lower(SYMB,TOK),
    scan(STR1,LIST).
```

the specific line that the compiler complains about is fronttoken(STR,SYMB,STR),!,
any help will be apreaciated thanks!

Comment: Silly question, but... is `fronttoken(_, _, _)` defined anywhere?

Comment: No, isn't it a preset predicate in prolog?

Comment: Oh. Indeed it might be. I used a very weird Prolog dialect :p

Comment: Well, the only thing that I can think of is... How are you calling this code? If you call it with `?- loop(X)`, it will call `scan` with two output arguments, which will in turn call `fronttoken` with three output arguments, which is not one of `fronttoken`'s flow patterns. If you call it with something concrete like `loop("test")`, then I am drawing a blank. EDIT: switched input for output, brain fart

Comment: (now that I've looked it up, `fronttoken` has these flow patterns: `(i,o,o) (i,i,o) (i,o,i) (i,i,i) (o,i,i)`)

Comment: loop is being called by the line    main:-write("Loading database file - please wait\n"),consult("project.dba"),readquery(L),loop(L).    and main is the goal being called in the program I don't know if that would lead to the problem you are talking about.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't. Can you trace scan, so you can see exactly how it's called and which variables are defined at that point?

Comment: Is there a program I can do this with I am using an old prolog compiler that I need to run through dos box and it doesn't have a trace scan feature to my knowlege.

Comment: As I said, I used a very weird Prolog dialect; wouldn't know. Try `write(STR)` just before `fronttoken`, see if that works correctly. I have a feeling `STR` is undefined, and that is why `fronttoken` is failing with that specific message. If not, I don't know.

Comment: As a side note, procedure scan/2 as shown in your question will either loop forever or fail... it will never succeed...

Comment: it's probable that the @gusbro observation could be the *answer*

Comment: actually I only took an exert of the code the next line is scan(_,[]). which will end the scan when the string is empty. I also tried putting a write(STR) in before fronttoken and it gave me an error that STR is a free variable.

Comment: That `STR` is a free variable when loop/1 is called is consistent with the error message about "flow pattern", i.e. that `frontoken/3` requires the first argument to be bound (but is called with a free argument there).  So the problem must lie in `readquery/1`.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are looking at an "ex[c]er[p]t" of the code, it's hard to be sure what is going wrong, but the the given evidence points to this:  `loop/1` is being called before `readquery/1` can do its work to populate (bind) the argument `STR` to `loop/1`.

Notice that `loop/1` calls itself (recursively), and does so in a repeat/fail pattern.  But the first time `loop/1` runs, there's no indication in the code shown of how argument `STR` would get populated.

A clearer (more self-contained) code snippet would be like this:

```
loop :- 
           readquery(STR),
           scan(STR,LIST),
           filter(LIST,LISroT1),
           pars(LIST1,LIST2),
           fail.

loop :-    loop.
```

This makes it clear that predicate `loop` doesn't actually return any result (and the given code snippet isn't complete enough to make clear what the program as a whole accomplishes).  It assumes that the clauses ahead of `fail` in `loop` are deterministic, so that in failing, control passes through to the second (recursive) clause of `loop/0`.  If this is not the case, the determinism could be forced by wrapping each call inside `once/1`.

Comment: in the code `scan(STR,[TOK|LIST]):-
    fronttoken(STR,SYMB,STR1),!,` the OP says they've added `write(STR)` in front of `fronttoken` and got "`STR` is a free var" error...  This can only mean that the code was copy-pasted from somewhere with some Unicode codes other than ASCII and needs to be typed over.

Comment: @WillNess: Thanks for fixing my broken "code" tags.  I took the OP's remark about inserting `write(STR)` to mean he/she "instrumented" the code to see what the value of `STR` was (and found that is was free/unbound) when `fronttoken` gets called.  How does this suggest a Unicode/ASCII mixup?

Comment: I thought it's like SWI's "Singleton variable" warning, e.g. with `p(X):- Y==1`.

Comment: @WillNess:  I suspect the OP is using an old Turbo Prolog version, based on the comment about running it through a "DOS box".  In any case SWI's warning is useful for catching those mistakes I seem to make regularly with misspelling (or incompletely revising) variable names, like using `STR` in the rule head but `Str` in the rule body.  That would certainly account for the variable being free... in fact there was just such a mistake in my revised code above!